# implode() array to insert record into mySql database

Tags: php, insert, mysqli, implode

I have a single row in a PHP array and I would like to insert that row into mySQL database by imploding the keys and values into a string and using those strings in my Insert statement as follows:

```
$fields = implode(",", array_keys($_POST));
$newdata = implode(",", $_POST);

$query = (
"INSERT INTO Food_entered ($fields)
VALUES ('$newdata')");

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

I am able to create the strings, and they appear to be in proper form ,however the row is not being inserted. Seems like a simple approach but not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: What are you getting back from the `$result`?

Comment: Hmmm....Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. Thought I checked that. Not sure why when I there are an equal number of keys and values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Barmar has pointed out, the problem is your quotes are on the outside of your variable.

I think this may be an easier to follow/cleaner way of fixing this however than the method Barmar posted:

```
$newdata = "'" . implode("','", $_POST) . "'";
```

Comment: I see that. I just needed to remove the double quote before implode and your suggestion worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

You need to quote each value, not the entire list of values:

```
$fields = implode(",", array_keys($_POST));
$newdata = implode(",", array_map(function($x) use ($dbc) {
    return "'" . $dbc->real_escape_string($x) . "'";
}, $_POST));

$query = (
"INSERT INTO Food_entered ($fields)
VALUES ($newdata)");

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Comment: Hello Barmar , kindly, this looks making things pretty automatic. Does this work if the rows are many? Or some cycle is needed?

Comment: @Robert If you try to use multiple `VALUES` lists in a single insert, make sure you don't exceed `max_allowed_packet`.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for the reply. Well, the rows will be not more than 20 or maximum 30. The poin is that I'm newbie. I have created one question here on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349503/php-mysql-insert-multimensional-associative-array-building-query-from-array-keys , can you kindly help me there? Thank you for any.

Comment: Or this solution applies exactly as in my question? If yes, just paste it there an I'll also provide to mark it as accepted (obviously) :-). Thank you for helping this noob ;-)

Comment: Ouch! Perfect, thank you for the duplicate question links.