# Optimizing INSERT sql with php-Mysql (Generate Sql Query from Json )

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hi guys how are you doing ?

This is my INSERT, gettin variables from the front end :

```
 function insert_evaluation() {  

/* Gettin tons of  POST variables from ANGULARJS 1.5 FRONT END*/
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));    


/* INSERTING TONS OF VARIABLES INTO MYSQL, I WOULD LIKE THIS TO BE AUTOMATED, WRITING .$data->idintervenant. FOR EXAMPLE IS REALLY ANNOYING GRRRRR. MY DREAM WOULD BE A LOOP THAT WOULD DO ALL OF THE JOB AUTOMATICALLY INSERTING THE VARIABLES AUTOMATICALLY IN THE RIGHT ORDER  */
$q = "INSERT INTO evaluations VALUES ('','".$data->idintervenant."','".$data->idresto."','".$data->noteglobale."','".$data->service."','".$data->ambiance."','".$data->attente."','".$data->caisses."','".$data->cuisines."','".$data->toilettes."')"; 

$qry = mysql_query($q);

 if ($qry) {
        $arr = array('msg' => "SUCCESS RECORD!!!", 'error' => '');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        // print_r($jsn);
    } else {
        $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'ERROR RECORDING');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        // print_r($jsn);
    }
    exit();  

}
```

Do you See how it is boring and time wasting to rewrite all the variables names  like .$data->noteglobale. for example ?!

The problem is that i don't want to re-write all the variables that are coming from the front end, I would like to automatize all of that ... I was thinking about a FOR loop ... Somebody have any idea ?

It would make it dynamic, for exemple if the front end sends 10 variables, and if lately,  if the ANGULARJS front end posts  12 variables to the PHP back end, it would still work, with only a SQL table modification !

My main problem : How not to rewrite the variables names and make it automatic ?

I need the insert to be generated automatically, i do not want to rewrite all the variables coming from the angularJs front end, do you see what i mean ?

**Edit 1** Finally I got this :

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);    
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($data));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($data));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
var_dump($escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO evaluations VALUES ($values)";
```

It's nearly working ! Except that i don't know how to add the first empty column , in my $value ... I would like to push an empty value (-> It's because of the auto increment-null situed at the first column in the table evaluations")

**Edit 2 :** Ok thanks a lot for your help it's finally working this is my code(Sorry for the french stuff) :

```
 function insert_evaluation() {  

    /* Récupération des données POST */
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);    
    $columns = implode(",",array_keys($data));
    var_dump($columns);

   $escaped_values = array_map('intval', array_values($data));
    $values  = implode(",", $escaped_values);
    var_dump($escaped_values);

$q = "INSERT INTO evaluations (idevaluation,".$columns.") VALUES (null,".$values.")";
    echo $q;

    $qry = mysql_query($q);

     if ($qry) {
            $arr = array('msg' => "Impression enregistree avec succès!!!", 'error' => '');
            $jsn = json_encode($arr);
            // print_r($jsn);
        } else {
            $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Erreur dans la mise à jour de l enregistrement');
            $jsn = json_encode($arr);
            // print_r($jsn);
        }
        exit();  

    }
```

An finally, the echo $q gives me this, a correct dynamic generated SQL query :

```
INSERT INTO evaluations (idevaluation,noteglobale,service,ambiance,attente,caisses,cuisines,toilettes,idintervenant,idresto) VALUES (null,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2)
```

I'll be using it on that : http://nicolash.org/evalueResto/

Tx for the security advices too !

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thank you, but what about my problem ?

Comment: I think the SQL injection is a bigger problem

Comment: Thank you a lot but it is not my question. There is no security features in my script, because its not my problem.

Comment: Those are your problems, solve them first

Comment: No HIHIHI, it's not the subject i'm working on right now. See let's say i've got 50 variables comin from the front end, i dont wanna get bored typing 50 of the variables into my insert SQL query i want this to be automatic ! Do you think it's possible ? I was thinking about a for loop generating the SQL insert ... But don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use a validation process before inserting the incoming data from the client, please use PDO objects to ensure you don't get SQL Injection.

And a easy way to insert all the values from the incoming object is by casting it as an array and use the implode function to have it as a string.

```html
<?php
$obj  = new stdClass();
$obj->test1 = 'data 1';
$obj->prop2 = 'data 2';

$query = 'INSERT INTO .... VALUES ("'.implode('","', (array)$obj) . '")';
echo $query;
```

Comment: Oh ok thank you a lot.. But i'm not using Pdo yet ... But if that's the only way, ok ..

Comment: Please note that in MySQL the values' order mathers when you don't specify the fields to be inserted.

Comment: I know i'm annoying, but is there any way to make it without PDO ? This seems pretty long to learn ...

Comment: Yes, with Prepared Statements, please check the two links below:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thank you it seems that i 've got something there also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757087/implode-array-to-insert-record-into-mysql-database